# Changing the Dash button to open a lens rather than shortcuts?

Tags: unity, configuration, unity-dash, lenses

I would like to change the default Dash opening screen from shortcuts (the "Home" page) to the Applications lens. Or at least to rebind the super key to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in Unity, however, starting with 12.04, if you select a lens, that will be the lens that is shown every time you open the Dash (in the state you left it in), until you log out or restart.

### Update:

While that was the intended behaviour, it does not work.

Comment: Man I wish that was true! The lenses retain state, but Dash always opens to the home page -- see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/946019  I created a bug, which was marked invalid because I was told to create a Brainstorm idea.  So I did, but that idea was marked as not-an-idea, because people are not permitted to make suggestions regarding Unity there.  Apparently, we have to go directly to the Atyana folks...so I tried that and they said they're not taking general input from people unless a launchpad issue has been filed.  OMFG!!!